# From sql datatable to string variable

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server Express database with tables

I use this code to store into a table

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\Company Management System\DBConn.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;");
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [GATE Activity] (activity, date)VALUES ('" +"Closed" + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") + "')", con);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.Close();
```

but now I need to do the exact opposite. I have a table called `PASSWORDS` with the first column called `password`

I want to copy the value from the last row into a string in C# called pass from example

Comment: Based on the C# and square braces, I removed the MySQL tag.

Comment: ***Please*** tell me you're ***not*** storing passwords in **clear text** in your database!!

Comment: No im not ^^ FEELING EMPTY NEED MORE KNOWLEDGE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this. Here is my solution, provided you have a primary key in Password table with int or identity or any field to recognize the order of record, identity is handy one, or some other column like createddate.

```
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" select top 1 password from [PASSWORDS] order by <ID> desc", con);
  SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  string last_pass = sdr["password"].ToString();
  if (!sdr.IsClosed) sdr.Close();
```

Here  is the field that i was referring earlier.

Comment: is this the way to use it coz im getting alot of errors here
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\Company Management System\DBConn.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;");
                        con.Open();
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" select top 1 password from [PASSWORDS] order by <ID> dec", con);
        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        string last_pass = sdr["password"].ToString();
        if (!sdr.IsClosed) sdr.Close();
                 con.Close();

Comment: What are errors you are getting?, Please replace <ID> with your primary key first,
Right way, is to put Connection string in Config.  And then write stored proc to execute DB calls.Then put all these codes DB access layer.

Comment: Error 5 Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration E:\Company Management System\Form2.cs 26 33 Company Management System

Comment: sorry i forgot to ask what is <ID> key

Comment: I had told you that it should be primary key of PASSWORDS table.

Comment: sorry Arindam i dont know what is primary key

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d95ec/1/0 , check this out, if you know SQL, you can understand from here

Comment: still no luck  , I'm still a beginner

Comment: Can you tell me columns and their type in PASSWORDS table, that will be helpful, and for primary key info -- http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp

Comment: PASSWORDS consists of two columns password and date 
the data type of password is nvarchar(50) and the data type of date is varchar(MAX) and now it only has one row password = 000000 date = Null

Comment: Either you have to add a primary key with identity, or change date's data type to datetime ( as it is date), or use order by CONVERT(Datetime, [date]) desc

Comment: I didnt really needed the date so i deleted the column , so i only have one column now which is password

Comment: I guess, you need to have atleast one column to identity last recent record, without that, i can't help you!

Comment: I have created one more SQL fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/074bc/1/0, check the procedure on left side, in this case you have to invoke this sp from C# code.

Comment: thanks you very much ,, I think i should study more before i ask